# How do I add a location to my path in Unix?

Tags: unix, path, freebsd, csh

I am using a default installation of FreeBSD, with the C shell (csh).

Suppose I have a command I can run by executing this: `/sbin/abc`, but cannot run by executing `abc`. How can I set certain path or something that make `abc` runnable everywhere?

Comment: http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BecomingRoot

Comment: what shell do you use?  setting your path is done slightly differently in bash, csh, sh, tcsh, etc.  You can generally run `echo $SHELL` to find out which shell you're using.

Comment: By the way, for `zsh` syntax, see [*Adding a new entry to the PATH variable in ZSH*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11530090/642706)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Aha, FreeBSD. That's tcsh, I believe.

So:

```
set path=(/sbin $path)
```

Answer (score 7):

[bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) & [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) syntax:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/sbin
```

[sh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_shell) syntax (two separate commands):

```
PATH=${PATH}:/sbin
export PATH
```

[csh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell) and [tcsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh):

> <strike>setenv PATH "${PATH}:/sbin"</strike>
>       set path=($path /sbin)

This will append `/sbin` to your path, so when you type `abc`, the shell will also look in `/sbin` for it. You can also add the command to your `~/.bashrc` file (or `~/.cshrc`, `~/.tcshrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.login`—depending on which shell you use).

Comment: I got "export command not found"  I am using Freebsd 8.1

Comment: Let me know which shell you're using, and I'll update the syntax.

Comment: I have no idea which shell I am using. It's default FreeBSD, i didn't change anything...

Comment: type `echo $SHELL` to find out which shell you're using, and run the appropriate commands (I'm guessing tcsh/csh since you don't have `export`).  I've updated this answer with syntax for all three.

Comment: /bin/csh         [ word padding...................]

Comment: This will work but csh and tcsh were intended to use the native wordlist variables and then PATH is generated automatically. Since the `setenv` command will *only* DTRT with PATH, it would be better for a tcsh user to learn the syntax that will work with all of his variables. The command he *should* be using is in my answer below.

Comment: @DigitalRoss, I forgot about that quirk of csh -- I mostly used bash.  Anyway, I updated the post.  @Andy, if `abc` is something you use a lot, you may want to put the command into your `~/.tcshrc` file, so you don't have to type it everytime you log in.